# Using USERNAME() measure in if condition in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a specific requirement, Where I would like make use of USERNAME() function available in Power BI in IF statement, the moment I use it I get below error:

```
CUSTOMDATA, USERNAME, USERCULTURE and USERPRINCIPALNAME functions are not supported in calculated tables/columns. These functions may only be used in Measures or in the AllowedRowsExpression.
```

I do know that we can create a measure as MeasureXYZ=USERNAME(), my requirement is to make use of this USERNAME() value in IF condition.

Seems to be like a product limitation, do we have any other way to get username apart from USERNAME(),USERPRINCIPALNAME etc?

Comment: "..not supported in **calculated tables/columns**" Are you getting this same error for your measure or only for a calculated column?

Comment: I first created the calculate measure. MeasureXYZ=USERNAME() , there was no issue. But when I make use of the calculated measure 'MeasureXYZ' to create a calculated column using IF condition, I get the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with `IF`.

As the error message indicates, you cannot use `USERNAME` or `USERPRINCIPALNAME` within a calculated column or a calculated table. This is for the same reason that you can't reference slicer selections in calculated columns/tables. I.e., the model is computed once when the data is loaded and not every time you change a slicer or visit with a new user.

That said, measures work fine with filters and usernames and the username function can be used as filters on your model via [Row-level security (RLS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls). I'd be surprised if what you are attempting to do cannot be achieved via measures or RLS.

Comment: I initially made use of RLS,I was also able to grab the RoleID of the logged in user from the Security table by creating a measure say 'GetRoleID' and making use of DAX function FIRSTNONBLANK in the measure definition.However when I make use of GetRoleID measure in IF condition in a calculated column it returned the first Role ID instead of the Role ID of the logged in user(which happened to be my 3rd Row).When I see the Security table in UI,it has been correctly filtered on the logged UserID but the Measure value doesn't takes the filtered context.

Comment: I understand that the model was already computed and hence the first non blank value was 1 but do we have a workaround to store or to retrieve the visible RoleID and use it in calculated column?

Comment: There is no workaround to get dynamic values into a calculated column. You need to abandon that approach.

Comment: It's very likely what you are ultimately trying to do is possible, just not the way you are trying to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

if your wanting to use a measure, this worked for me

Current User = if(USERNAME() = "domain\user","its me","it aint me")

Obv would need to swap in your domain and user name

Comment: Not looking for a measure, I instead want to use the value of this measure in a calculated column in a IF condition. Usage of USERNAME() is not permitted at calculated column level.

Comment: If you need it as a calculated column then power bi doesnt support it. Which makes sense as a calculated column is evaluated when the database is refreshed (row context), not when a user is using your report (so not filter context). 
So a calculated column would never know the username


There is a good article from Adam saxton [about using username with RLS](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-username-in-dax-with-row-level-security/) and another from chris web explaining [calculated columns & measures](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/)